# Conditional and Biconditional Statements Exercise

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Going through Velleman's *How to Prove it*, I came across the problem:

Prove $(P \rightarrow R) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R) = (P \vee Q) \rightarrow R$

Solution:
$$(\neg P \vee R) \wedge (\neg Q \vee R)............(1)$$
$$(\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee R).................(2)$$
$$\neg(P \vee Q) \vee R = (P \vee Q) \rightarrow R$$

I understand how they got implies to become a boolean formula with just $\neg$ and $\vee$, however I don't know what they did to get from (1) to (2). When I attempted it I expanede (1) to become $$[(\neg P \vee R) \wedge \neg Q] \vee [(\neg P \vee R) \wedge R]$$ and attempted to expand/ condense from there. Could someone tell me what they did to get from (1) to (2) or better yet why my attempt isn't the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: You have to use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: Then use [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: In my attempt, I distributed and got the last boolean formula above, [(¬∨)∧¬]∨[(¬∨)∧]. Are you saying I should use de Morgan's law now? Also, would I have to use it twice since I need to retain the same truth value.

Comment: Looking through the wikipedia article on Distributivity, I thought I did that???

Comment: Distributivity $(R\lor (\lnot P\land \lnot Q))\Leftrightarrow ((R \lor \lnot P)\land (R\lor \lnot Q))$ is an equivalence; thus, it can be used "both ways". In your problem you have the RHS (1) and you can replace it with the LHS (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something that's very common to beginning students of logic!

Distribution says that:

$P \land (Q \lor R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$

Now, what students often don't realize is that this is an equivalence. That is, you can go from left to right, but you can also go from right to left.

Of course, going from right to left that doesn't feel like a 'Distribution' ... more like a 'Un-Distribution', or maybe 'Reverse Distribution' ... maybe think of it as 'Factoring' or 'Collecting common terms'... but in the end, it is still called Distribution.

So, in your case, when you have $(\neg P \lor R) \land (\neg Q \lor R)$, you can see this as the *result* of a Distribution of $R$ over $(\neg P \land \neg Q)$, so if we do a 'Reverse' Distribution, you take out the common $R$, and end up with $(\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor R$

See how that works?

Comment: Oh,that makes so much sense! Thank you!

Comment: @WilsonGuo You're welcome, glad I could help! :)